# Edition Compatibility between SQL Server 2012 "Evaluation" Edition and "Enterprise" & "Standard" Edition

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm Newbie to SQL Server 2012 , I found out that there are paid and free editions of SQL Server 2012​ available ​.

those are

```
 1.Enterprise [paid]

 2.Business Intelligence [paid ]

 3. Standard [paid]

 4. WEB [paid]

 5. Express [free]

 6. Evaluation  [free]

 7. Developer [free,paid]
```

Now I have ambiguity between ​paid version and Free versions . because ​there are some restrictions bind with paid versions ​as well as​ ​free versions ​.​

But I decided to install SQL Server 2012 "Evaluation" Edition Since my project lightweight and Non Profitable.

So I just want to know if I use  SQL Server 2012 "Evaluation" Edition will it be compatible with rest of the above editions

For an example consider this scenario:

```
 if I Generate DB from SQL Server 2012 "Evaluation"  Edition , then I add add some tables and data into it.then I deattache it ,
```

My Question is ,

Will I able to restore above DB on a server that SQL Server 2012 "Evaluation" or "Enterprise" Edition Installed ?

Comment: Yes, There's no issues with compability of the products. Only differences are the features where paid ones have more features than free or evaluation versions.

Comment: Simply , db dump of SQL Server 2012 “Evaluation” Edition, will  work on “Enterprise” or “Standard” Edition ?

Comment: If you mean Attaching the MDF file to new Enterprise or Standard edition then YES.

Comment: Evaluation = Developer = Enterprise. The difference *is* in the licensing. You can't use Evaluation/Developer in a production environment. But they give you "the good stuff" to get you hooked.

Comment: okay thank you all , I'm satisfied